# Missing link on profile to view recently deleted questions

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, user-profile

I recently deleted a question that wasn't well-received by the community since it was unclear. However, there is no way for me to see it. My understanding is that there [should be a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile) to my recently deleted questions, but I see no such link on my profile.

[image: Screenshot of my profile]

This issue might be evident for users that do not have any non-deleted questions for the site (see comment below which seems to verify this behavior).

As mentioned by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) on the meta question linked above, this appears to be a bug. Can someone confirm and help fix the issue? Thanks.

Edit: I can confirm that this bug appears if a user has no other visible questions for a SE site. I've since asked a new question on arqade and the link is now clearly visible on my profile.

Comment: I can reproduce, but only on sites where I have no questions.

Comment: @murgatroid99: That is fantastic information! Sounds like we might have the set of conditions for this bug since I also have no other questions other than the one I deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The link is a little hard to find. Click "questions", then there should be a link for recently deleted questions. I see it on your profile, and the question appears (as a mod, I can see these for any user, whereas you will just be able to see your own).

Does anything appear when you go [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/68492) (That is the page that is referred to with that link. I can see your question there.)?

Comment: Yes, I absolutely see the question in the link you provide. However, no such link exists on my profile as I note in the screenshot of the questions tab on my profile. My understanding from Shog9 is that the link should still exist (see the most recent comments on his answer).

Comment: When I go to your profile, if I click your "questions" link (the bold in that picture), I see the link for you that leads to the page I posted here. So I am not sure what the issue is, because I can't reproduce it. :(

Comment: I'm a web applications developer and we have a popular phrase around here at my office: "It works on my machine."

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right for the situation. Maybe someone other than me might be better help (I am not sure if my being a mod here is affecting anything or not.)

Comment: Well, like I mentioned to Shog9 when initially asking about it, I'm not heartbroken over it. And I have this question to link back to it through the answer you provided. But if it really is a bug, I wanted to report it.

Comment: @user11502 According to the link in the question, mods are the only people other people who can see your deleted questions list. So there's probably some special logic for mods.